# Decorators and variables scope

Tags: python, scope, python-decorators, monkeypatching

I am writing a (`python3`) program and I got stuck when trying to implement a (function) decorator which updates an external variable, a kind of signal emitting decorator. The problem is the conflict with various functions scopes. I have look around to some similar problems but I haven't found yet the useful one... I need to respect, if possible, some design restrictions (see below) and I also would like do avoid to use external libraries.

Here a working example with the `global`keyword which can be useful as starting point

```
VAR = 'i am a global variable'


# decorator
def update_external_variable():
    def f_wrapper(f):
        def p_wrapper(p, q):
            r = f(p, q) + ': updating the global variable ??'
            global VAR
            VAR = r
            return r
        return p_wrapper
    return f_wrapper

@update_external_variable()
def a(p, q): return 'a({}, {})'.format(p, q)    #target function
o = a('v', 'w')

print(VAR, id(VAR))
```

Ouput

```
a(v, w): updating the global variable ?? 140497617759280 # yes, it works!
```

**Design restriction 1:** the decorator, `update_external_variable`, should not depend on the external variable identifier (name), so it has to be passed as parameter. The signature of `update_external_variable` should contains the info of the global variable, `VAR`.

Attempt 1: *the mokey patch way* - I tried mimic the above working example but with no results

```
VAR = 'i am a global variable'

# decorator
def update_external_variable(ext_var_id):   # ext_var_id: string with the variable identifier
    def f_wrapper(f):
        def p_wrapper(p, q):
            r = f(p, q) + ': updating the global variable ??'

            exec('global {}'.format(ext_var_id), {})            # -> global VAR
            exec('{} = "{}"'.format(ext_var_id, eval(ext_var_id))) # initialize VAR??
            #print(dir())
            return r
        return p_wrapper
    return f_wrapper

@update_external_variable(ext_var_id='VAR')
def a(p, q): return 'a({}, {})'.format(p, q)    #target function


o = a('v', 'w')
print(o, id(o))
```

Output

```
a(v, w): updating the global variable ?? 140686557781040
i am a global variable         # failure!
```

Attempt 2: the parameters' way

```
VAR = 'i am a global variable'

# decorator
def update_external_variable(ext_var):  # ext_var: reference of the global variable
    def f_wrapper(f):
        def p_wrapper(p, q, ext_var=ext_var):
            r = f(p, q) + ': updating the global variable ??'
            # global ext_var <- will raise to an error since point to the parameter..
            print(ext_var)
            ext_var = r
            return r
        return p_wrapper
    return f_wrapper


@update_external_variable(ext_var=VAR)
def a(p, q): return 'a({}, {})'.format(p, q)  # target function


o = a('v', 'w')
print(o, id(o))
print(VAR)
```

Output

```
i am a global variable
a(v, w): updating the global variable ?? 140406972742896
i am a global variable       # failure!
```

**Design restriction 2**: if a solution using the *attempt 2* exist then I need to impose the following restriction on the signature of the `p_wrapper` which can could give rise to further problems: `def p_wrapper(*args, **kwargs): ...` To give to the decorator a universal fingerprint I need that the arguments of `p_wrapper` to be those of the function to be decorated, `r = func(*args, **kwargs)`.

If someone has an idea on how to solve this problem, it can be either for Attempt 1 or Attempt 2 or even combination of them or another solution as well, I will be very grateful!

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: If your requirement is to take the name of a global variable as an argument to the decorator, you should be using an explicit global dict whose *keys* can be used as arguments to the decorator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use individual global variables; use a `dict` that your decorated function can update.

```
VARS = {
    'var1': ...,
    'var2': ...,
}

# decorator
def update_external_variable(varkey):
    def f_wrapper(f):
        def p_wrapper(p, q):
            r = f(p, q) + ': updating the global variable ??'
            VARS[varkey] = r
            return r
        return p_wrapper
    return f_wrapper

@update_external_variable('var1')
def a(p, q): 
  return 'a({}, {})'.format(p, q)    #target function

o = a('v', 'w')

print(VARS['var1'])
```

If, for whatever reason, your decorator must work with existing global variables that you can't change, use `globals()` to get access to the necessary `dict`.

```
VAR1 = ...
VAR2 = ...

# decorator
def update_external_variable(varkey):
    def f_wrapper(f):
        def p_wrapper(p, q):
            r = f(p, q) + ': updating the global variable ??'
            globals()[varkey] = r
            return r
        return p_wrapper
    return f_wrapper

# Still passing the *name* of the variable as a string
@update_external_variable('VAR1')
def a(p, q): 
  return 'a({}, {})'.format(p, q)    #target function

o = a('v', 'w')

print(VAR1)
```

Comment: 1. I cannot consider your 1st answer as a solution since the body of the decorator has still the dependency of smt external, the dictionary itself 2. that's closer... using the globals built-in is a bit brute force (for security reason), any ideas on how to gather writing access to VAR through all the nested name spaces using global, nonlocal, parameters, eval, .... more in the direction to understand the syntax/paradigm behind the variable scopes

Comment: If you have to dynamically access a variable *name*, design restriction 1 is broken, and should be revisited.

Comment: The design restriction 1 can give rise to confusion, it could be biased from my previous attempts to solve the problem, sorry for that. Maybe would be better like this "the **body** of the decorator, update_external_variable, should not **explicitly** depend on the external variable identifier (name), so it has to be passed as parameter. [...]" or just remove it. As in the Attempt 1 I tried to use a monkey patch approach and the variable identifier was needed and passed as a parameter (so not explicitly).